# Цикл foreach выполняет лишь часть действий в корутине

Tags: kotlin

В приложении пользуюсь Room для доступа к БД. Логика написана согласно мануалу гугла(MVVM). Возникла проблема с одной функцией в репозитории, которая почему-то сама останавливается.
Код в ViewModel:

```
fun moveNotes(list: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repository.moveNotes(TypeConverter.stringToListLong(list))
}
```

Код в репозитории:

```
suspend fun moveNotes(list: MutableList<Long>) {

    var note: Notes
    list.forEach {
        note = getNote(it)
        note.grouped = true
        notesDao.update(note) // ведет к suspend-функции в DAO
        if(!ids.contains(it)) {
            ids.add(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Итак, к проблеме. Спустя один-два цикла функция останавливается после строки `notesDao.update(note)`(3-ая строка цикла). Выяснил, что если если убрать ее из цикла, то цикл полностью отрабатывает. Сама по себе эта функция в DAO рабочая, в других функциях, а также без корутин работала.
Код в DAO:

```
@Update
suspend fun update(notes: Notes)
```

Как думаете, в чем проблема?

UPD: Привязку к модели делаю так

```
var mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: просто останавливается или вылетает? попробуйте repository.moveNotes завернуть в try catch и посмотрите будет ли ошибка какая

Comment: @IR42 вы правы, получил в логе Exception "Job was cancelled"

Comment: @IR42 вы случайно не знаете с чем это связано? Просто реализацию корутин в Room я взял из мануала гугла, потому не совсем еще в них разбираюсь.

Comment: ну вообще это означает, что вы либо выходите с экрана и ViewModel уничтожается, отменяя при этом viewModelScope и все запущенные корутины в этом скоупе, либо вы сами отменяете job, который возвращается при вызове `fun moveNotes(list: String)`

Comment: @IR42 я тут подумал над вашим сообщением и вроде понял в чем дело. Почти все действия в репозитории через модель выполняет главное активити и там все нормально, а вот moveNotes запускает специальный DialogFragment, который тоже имеет доступ к модели. Просто я думал, что раз все активити и фрагменты все имеют доступ к одной модели, то важен лишь ее lifecycle(т.е. наличие хоть одного живого компонента). Получается, когда убивается фрагмент, то и Job отменяется, даже несмотря на то, что к модели привязано живое активити?

Comment: Если модель привязана к активити, то она не должна уничтожаться, скорей всего вы как-то не так её получаете во фрагменте и создаётся новая модель с привязкой к фрагменту, вставьте код привязки

Comment: @IR42 добавил в конец поста строку привязки к модели. И активити, и фрагмент привязываю одинаково. В старых мануалах еще видел ViewModelProviders вместо ViewModelProvider. Но не думаю, что в этом дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во `ViewModelProvider` передаётся тот компонент (`ViewModelStoreOwner`) из которого будет браться и к которому будет привязываться нужная вам `ViewModel`.
У вас во фрагменте вы передаёте `this`, т.е. сам фрагмент как `ViewModelStoreOwner`, поэтому создаётся новая `ViewModel` и привязывается к этому фрагменту. При выходе из данного фрагмента `ViewModel` уничтожается, отменяя все корутины.
Если во фрагменте нужно получить `ViewModel` из активити, то в `ViewModelProvider` нужно передавать активити.

```
mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: @Viktor пошарить вьюмодель между активити навряд ли получиться, хотя вроде можно через Navigation Component сделать, с привязкой вьюмодели к графу, но там продвигается концепция Single Activity, а сами экраны это фрагменты, так что такая проблема там не стоит, других способов не знаю, да и MVVM вроде как не подразумевает шарить вьюмодельки, просто особенности реализации в андройде. Вообще не обязательно же  viewModelScope использовать, можно и свой создать CoroutineScope, который не будет помирать с вьюмоделью

Comment: пока не умею особо с корутинами работать. Моя реализация с привязкой к viewModelScope взята и адаптирована с мануала гугла. Ну ладно, с фрагментами поделить модель получилось, а с активити в принципе не надо, оно же не закрывается мгновенно, как мои DialogFragment, корутина успевает отработать свое.